# How to convert Resources.LoadAll to Addressables?

Tags: unity, assets, loading, asset-management, addressable

I have been advised to move away from the Resources system to the new Addressables system, which seems to have many advantages.

I need to convert the following code to use the Addressables:

```
public static void LoadDefs()
{
    foreach (var baseTileType in Resources.LoadAll(Settings.BASE_TILES_PATH, typeof(TextAsset)))
    {
        var baseTile = Deserializer.Deserialize<BaseTile.Initializer>(((TextAsset) baseTileType).text);
        BaseTileInstances.Add(baseTile.Name, baseTile.CreateInstance());
    }

}
```

It is important for me to detect the type of `TextAsset` because those are .yaml files that I need to load the information from. Then, derived from information in that YAML file, I load sprites that I need with `Resources.Load<Sprite>(path)` later, but that should be simple.

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.11/manual/AddressableAssetsMigrationGuide.html#the-resource-folders-method) is pretty unclear on how to do this. It mentions labels, but not much else.

How can I achieve a similar result with this new system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a basic solution for the following problem. Here's an example of needing to load and store sprites:

1. Add your `addressables` into a group and label them accordingly. In my case, `"pictures"`.

[image: addressables view]

2. Add the code.

   ```
   public static readonly Dictionary<string, Sprite> AllSprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();

   public static async Task InitSprites(string assetLabel)
   {
       var locations = await Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync(assetLabel, typeof(Sprite)).Task;
       List<Task<Sprite>> tasks = new List<Task<Sprite>>();

       foreach (var location in locations)
       {
           tasks.Add(Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>(location).Task);
       }

       var loadedSprites = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

       foreach (var sprite in loadedSprites)
       {
           AllSprites.Add(sprite.name, sprite);
       }
   }
   ```

You may call `InitSprites` from any async method. For example, you can define a `public static async void Load()` method, which you call from the `Start()` method in your `GameManager` singleton.

Then, inside of that, call `await InitSprites("pictures")`. This will asynchronously load and store your sprites wherever you need (in my case, a dictionary).

3. Modify

You can get this code to work with any asset type. All you have to do is to replace the `typeof()` parameter with your desired type. You can even write `typeof(object)` and then store it into a `List<object>`. That way, one list can hold ALL of your assets of various types, which you can then use however you like.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for sharing. I can see a case when this would need to be revisited again, you are loading by labels, so my understanding is that it will load any asset with that label even if it's outside target group. Also, if you need different labels inside of your group, you might want to load whole group. If you want to load multiple groups without labels then a `Type` would be the identifier to define what asset to load or not. But main thing, it's similar to `Resources` but it's not the same, if you were loading all assets from a group of some `Type` it would be more similar to it.

Comment: True, this approach is a bit limited by labels. LoadResourcesLocationsAsync() requires some "key" identifier - it seems supplying only the type isn't enough for it to find assets. We would need to identify a whole group and then look for Types in there, but I'm not sure how to do that yet. Will update answer if I find out.

Comment: Yep, that is okay if we can access the whole group but Unity seems to think that we don't need that - https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-load-addressable-group-load-several-assets-at-once.778352/ , unless I am confused with the things in the forum thread.

Comment: I have found a somewhat decent workaround if you are interested. You can manage your labels from code and create a new label for each new group. Then you can assign this label to each addressable asset when it gets moved around. In the end your loading with labels is a valid solution for this when we use this approach to define if asset is in a certain group. Check out my previous comment with a link, there are a lot more details in that thread from `Pixel Lifetime` about this.

Comment: The way I see it, groups are useless. Whether you define multiple labels in one group, or one label per multiple groups, in the end the result will be the same as you always load by label with this approach. Correct me if I missed something.

Comment: As I understand groups are used as editor tool to group assets together into packages that are loaded together. But they are non-existent in Runtime sense, during play mode etc. Thus we have to use labels to load groups of objects at runtime, basically we are grouping objects in our own way by using labels. But we can automate that process - each time an asset is moved into another group, we can access that group in editor, see what is their label (the one we created for ourselves automatically) and reassign label of the asset to be this group's label. Now we have grouping using labels.

Comment: You are right that we are loading by label. But conceptually we are splitting some labels per group. Imagine you have a project where you manage lots of assets. Each time you add an asset to a group, you have to assign a correct label, if this was automated then asset would be assigned a group's unique label, you wouldn't have to worry about doing that yourself, might save some manual errors and some time. You can still assign other labels to assets, so it's even more flexible because you can have other "imaginary" groups of assets.

Comment: It might not make much sense for some projects. When I talk about things like that, I imagine using Addressables for loading and asset management in an offline PC game. Where you load scenes, runtime assets, scriptable object singletons, etc - all using Addressables.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, however, the approach I took is to just have one group with folders. When you assign a label to a folder, it applies to all its contents. That way, when I add a new thing to a certain folder, it automatically gets the needed label. You can see my structure here: https://prnt.sc/1b2qo04

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is also valid approach if it gives you a solution. Didn't know that it's automatic labelling inside a folder.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this is more or less efficient than the OPs solution, but here is my take on the same problem. In my case, I have lots of different data types that derive from scriptable objects that I loaded by type into lists at runtime using Resources.LoadAll(). Some have prefabs which means they have dependencies thus making the main data payload quite large (project is WebGL), so moving these out of resources to load from addressables was critical. Like OP, I organize the Addressable assets with labels and groups. Instead of using `System.Threads.Task` I'm using the familiar Monobehaviour Coroutine, because, well, I'm familiar with it :)

```
IEnumerator  LoadAssetsAsync<T>(string label, List<T> list, System.Type type)
    {
        yield return null;
        AsyncOperationHandle<IList<IResourceLocation>> handle = Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync(label, type);
        yield return handle;

        for(int i = 0; i < handle.Result.Count; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine (LoadAssetAsync<T>(handle.Result[i], list));
        }
        Addressables.Release(handle);
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAssetAsync<T>(IResourceLocation location, List<T> list)
    {
        var handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<T>(location);
        yield return handle;
        list.Add(handle.Result);
    }
```

And it gets called like so:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>(); //Foo can be anything

void OnGameAwake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadAssetsAsync<Foo>("Foo", foos, typeof(Foo)));
    }
```

Probably just a dumber way of restating the OPs solution, but it works...